# Regular expression executing before the other one

Tags: compilation, flex-lexer, lex, compiler-construction

i am having a problem with my code

```
alphabet [a-zA-Z] 
var  {alphabet}+[{chiffre}{alphabet}_]*
{varIntDecl} {
        for(int i=5 ;i<yyleng;i++)tab[cmp].token[i-5]=yytext[i]; strcpy(tab[cmp].value,"0");strcpy(tab[cmp].type,"Var"); 

            tab[cmp].indiceTS= cmp;

                strcpy(tab[cmp++].typeValeur,"int");

                    yylval.indiceTS=cmp;

                        return (INTVARIABLEDECL);

        }

{var} {

        for(int i=0;i<cmp;i++){

                    if(!strcmp(tab[i].token,yytext)) {

                            return (VARINT);

                            }
        }
            printf("Error Variable non trouvé Please Declare First ");
    }



varIntDecl {int}{blancs}{var};
```

when i'm executing this 
i have  a yacc part but it's irrelevant to this

i'm getting this conflict of var executing everytime even tho it's not what i wanted to do

here is the result of execution:

- int abc

> Error Variable non trouvé Please Declare First

- int adc

> Error Variable non trouvé Please Declare First

Comment: Please reread the [flex manual on patterns](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html). In particular, the following sentence: ***Note that inside of a character class, all regular expression operators lose their special meaning except escape (`\ `) and the character class operators, `-`, `]`, and, at the beginning of the class, `^`.*** You would get into less trouble if you didn't use macro definitions like `{chiffre}`; `[0-9]` is quite clear, or you can use [named character classes](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html#index-patterns_002c-valid-character-classes).

Comment: Also, you need to explicitly NUL-terminate any strings you expect to behave properly with C standard library functions.